# Brackets IDE: fix it?

Tags: html, css, macos, adobe-brackets

I have some problems with Brackets redactor. When I use sublime, save html & css code, then open it through chrome by clicking on index.html, it works good: http://rghost.ru/7NCLNdtBJ
But when i use Live Preview in brackets, brackets open my chrome and show this:http://rghost.ru/6D25SVNFC

What's the problem, and how i can fix it?

Comment: It looks like the path to your css is not specific enough for the Brackets live preview.

Comment: @Jack How can i change path for Brackets live preview?

Comment: What is the path to your css file?

Comment: @Jack in index.html i wrote <link href="/Users/artyom/Documents/Project/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> and when i open index.html through chrome with clicks, it works. It doesnt work, when i use brackets preview

Comment: It looks like `Project` is your root directory. See my answer below and set your css path to `/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: @Jack It works! Thank you man, I understood! U are the best)

Comment: Great! Consider Accepting my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `css` folder in your root directory, you can link to it like this:

```
/css/styles.css
```

---

More info:

> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward

Copied from: http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/